# Libgdx : No implementation found for native Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidGL20;.init ()V

Tags: android, opengl-es-2.0, libgdx

For a while now i am making a game with libgdx and I only had tried it on desktop ,now when i try to run it on my phone it throws this:

```
11-02 23:16:19.171: W/GL2JNIView(2702): creating OpenGL ES 2.0 context
11-02 23:16:19.211: D/dalvikvm(2702): Trying to load lib /data/data/com.infiniteangle.raywararcade/lib/libgdx.so 0x40514af0
11-02 23:16:19.211: D/dalvikvm(2702): Shared lib '/data/data/com.infiniteangle.raywararcade/lib/libgdx.so' already loaded in same CL 0x40514af0
11-02 23:16:19.211: W/dalvikvm(2702): No implementation found for native Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidGL20;.init ()V
11-02 23:16:19.211: W/dalvikvm(2702): Exception Ljava/lang/UnsatisfiedLinkError; thrown while initializing Lcom/badlogic/gdx/backends/android/AndroidGL20;
11-02 23:16:19.221: W/dalvikvm(2702): threadid=8: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015568)
11-02 23:16:19.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2702): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 9
11-02 23:16:19.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2702): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
11-02 23:16:19.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2702):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.setupGL(AndroidGraphics.java:286)
11-02 23:16:19.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2702):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGraphics.onSurfaceCreated(AndroidGraphics.java:334)
11-02 23:16:19.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2702):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1348)
11-02 23:16:19.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2702):     at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1118)
11-02 23:16:19.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2702): Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: init
11-02 23:16:19.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2702):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20.init(Native Method)
11-02 23:16:19.221: E/AndroidRuntime(2702):     at com.badlogic.gdx.backends.android.AndroidGL20.<clinit>(AndroidGL20.java:28)
```

The game is using OpenGL es 2.0

My libs folder looks like this:

[image]

I tried restarting eclipse(just in case) ,cleaning project.

Comment: hhmmm I think it makes no sense to supply the gl20.so files. Either your phone natively supports OGL ES 2, or it doesn't.

Comment: The gdx project creator automatically puts these files in the libs folder . My phone totally supports opengl es 2

Comment: You mean the gdx-setup-ui? For me it didn'T put those libs there.

Comment: Did you use `gdx-setup-ui`?  Which version of libgdx are you using?

Comment: @P.T. ,yes I used gdx-setup-ui , i am using the version that was the stable one 2 months ago when I downloaded it :) , how do i see the version of the jar?.Should i re-download and update all the gdx jars ?Is any chance this will fix it or is it another kind of problem?

Comment: You're probably using 0.9.7, which should be fine.  Is there anything really unusual about your device?  (e.g., its x86 based or something?)  One other thing to check is if any part of your device's storage is full.  The Libgdx native libraries get copied around as part of startup, so out-of-space errors might break them.  (Though I would expect it to get reported more directly....)

Comment: so did u get this solved?

Comment: @Maysam , actually no,my android phone broke and i didnt had another android phone available o test it :(,i am starting to think that maybe was the rom I had putted on it ,maybe it didnt had the opengl 2.0 drivers or something like that...

Comment: i am using original device and still same problem, anyway i probably just move on with my own code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I replaced all of the libgdx's jars with the new version,probably many of the jars were outdated